# Haskell Functions and Mapping

Tags: function, haskell, dictionary

This is a homework assignment, and I'm really struggling with the last bit. We are writing "Battleship" in Haskell, and aside from a few general lectures on Functional Languages, we don't have much to go on. No textbook, etc.. I've been referred to LYAH a few times, and there's good stuff there, but it doesn't seem to have suggestions for this particular issue.

For context, I'll put my entire Battleship code up so you can see what definitions I'm referencing later.

```
--A
data Row = A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J deriving (Enum, Ord, Show, Bounded, Eq, Read)
data Column = One | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten  deriving (Enum, Ord, Show, Bounded, Eq, Read)
--B
data Address = Address Row Column deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
--C
data Cell = Cell Address Bool deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
--D
data Ship = Ship [Cell] deriving (Show, Eq)
--E
data Ships = Ships [Ship] deriving (Show, Eq)
--F
toAddress r c = Address (toEnum r) (toEnum c)
--G
toRowColumn (Address aRow aColumn) = (fromEnum aRow, fromEnum aColumn)
--H
allAddressesA = [ Address row column | row <- [A .. J], column <- [One .. Ten]]
--I
allAddressesB = [toAddress row column | row <- [0 .. 9], column <- [0 .. 9]]
--J
targetShip (Ship ship) (Address row column)
  | Address == map (\list -> (head Address Bool)) s
--K
targetShips [(Ships)] toAddress //TODO
--L
isSunk Ship ship
  |ship [] = true
  |otherwise foldl 
--M
areSunk [(Ships)] //TODO
```

And now I'll also post the specific assignment descriptions too so there isn't any communication errors with what I need help with:

> (j) Write a function targetShip that accepts a Ship and a target
>   address as its two parameters. If the ship has a cell with the target
>   address, that cell is marked sunk. An updated version of the ship is
>   returned. If the ship is empty, the empty Ship is returned. (1 map,
>   116 characters)
>
> (k) Write a function targetShips that accepts a list
>   of Ships and a target address as its two parameters. It attempts to
>   sink each ship in the ship list. It returns a list of updated ships.
>   If no ships are present, the empty list is returned. (1 map, 86
>   characters)
>
> (l) Write a function isSunk that accepts a Ship as its
>   parameter. If the ship is the empty ship, return true. Otherwise,
>   return true if all cells are marked sunk. (1 fold, 78 characters)
>
> (m) Write a function areSunk that accepts a list of Ships as its
>   parameter. If no ships are present, return true. Otherwise, return
>   true if all ships are marked sunk. (1 fold, 78 characters)

So what my particular struggle here is, is these last 4. Solutions (A - I) I have tested and they work just fine.

We need to know how to reference cell values...the Address and the Bool separately, for starters.

We can't write more functions.

I will assume that you'll want more of an explanation on particular issues, so I'll be monitoring closely. Any hints on where to begin for the last four problems will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance...and I'll be headed back to my text editor now and trying to work this out as well.

Comment: I'm guessing the upvotes are from classmates also wanting to know the answer to this ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (j) Write a function targetShip that accepts a Ship and a target address as its two parameters. If the ship has a cell with the target address, that cell is marked sunk. An updated version of the ship is returned. If the ship is empty, the empty Ship is returned. (1 map, 116 characters)

function `targetShip`,
parameters `Ship and a target address as its two parameters`
produce `Ship is returned`

These information are enough to write down a type annotation for your function.

```
targetShip :: Ship -> Address -> Ship
targetShip (Ship ship) (Address row column)
```

`If the ship is empty, the empty Ship is returned`
And a ship is a list or a list is either an empty list [] or the a head with a tail, then

```
targetShip :: Ship -> Address -> Ship
targetShip (Ship []) (Address row column) = Ship []
targetShip (Ship (x:xs)) (Address row column) =
```

Now the hard part.
`If the ship has a cell with the target address, that cell is marked sunk`
A ship is a list of cell, then surly I need for each cell (defined the ship) to check if the address of the current cell are the same that the one provided by the argument of the function.
Ok, let do it for the head `x` emerged by our pattern matching.

```
targetShip :: Ship -> Address -> Ship
targetShip (Ship []) (Address row column)     = Ship []
targetShip (Ship (x:xs)) (Address row column) = 
    if x ...
```

OMG, I can't do it, as no helper function are allow, I need more info. I need to emerge the structure of the x into my pattern matching, like so,

```
targetShip (Ship ((Cell address bool):xs)) (Address row column) =
```

OMG again, I can't do more, ok redo the same thing, being more expressive in my pattern matching.

```
targetShip (Ship ((Cell (Address shipRow shipColumn) bool):xs)) (Address row column) =
```

Now it's ok I can do it.
And I will let you finish it.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation. Two important guidance, type annotation and pattern matching, it's really helpful.

Comment: Thanks a ton :) We've been able to move on to targetShips which is recursively calling targetShip, and we're cruising now :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

J: You have to return a ship with a new list that depends on the address.

```
targetShip (Ship oldCells) address = Ship newCells
  where newCells = ...
        f cell =
```

How do you figure out the new cells? The task suggests using a map. So you could map a function `f` over `oldCells`. What should `f` do? If it gets a cell that has the same address as the argument to targetShip, it should return a new cell with the same address, but with a sunken status. Otherwise it should just return the cell given as an argument.

K: Should be very easy, once you get targetship working. Follow the suggestion to use `map`.

L and J: Very similar. The tasks suggest using a fold. Have you tried using a fold before? There are two basic kinds, `foldr` and `foldl`, they both work by taking a function that takes two arguments, an accumulator and a current element, and folding the list into the accumulator one element at a time, using a given accumulator. Let me show you some examples of foldl in action.

```
foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) 0 [1,2,3] -> 6 -- starting accumulator of 0
foldl (+) 0 [1,2,3] -> 6 -- same thing as above
foldl (&&) True [True, True, True] -> True -- folding booleans
foldl (&&) True [True, False, True] -> False -- more boolean folding
foldl (&&) True [] -> True -- folding an empty list yields the initial accumulator
foldl (\acc x -> acc && (x > 5)) True [6,7,8] -> True -- complex folding function.
```

With the last function I hope you are able to see, how you can solve problems L and J. Otherwise look at pattern matching in anonymous functions and check out [folding](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#folds) in LYAH.

Comment: Hey @Boris, thanks a bunch, this is a great response. I understand how folding goes according to your answer, but, I fail to see how to apply them to L and J. Checking out LYAH now, meanwhile, do you have an example that might fit into this context a little more?

Comment: @Joodoo: Do you see how, in the last example, each list element is being transformed into a boolean based on whether it satisfies some criterion (being above 5 in this case)? The example in effect tests if every list element satisfies that criterion. This is similar to what you need for L and J. In L you should return true, if every ship cell is marked as sunk. To get that, your anonymous function should use pattern matching on its arguments to easily get to the sunken status. What is the criterion that every ship should satisfy in task J?